# jquery-forms multiple file input fieldValue()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery forms and I have a multiple file input.  I want to show the name of the files selected before submission.  I can use the fieldValue method as below for a single file; however, contrary to my expectations, fieldValue()  returns an array with a single element, even when multiple files are selected.

```
.on('change', function(event){
    var fArray = $("#upload :file").fieldValue();
    var nameStr = "";
    for(var i = 0 ; i < fArray.length ; i++ ){
       ...
```

I looked in the chrome debugger and can find the file names.  `event.currentTarget.files` but I don't know how to get them from jquery/javascript.  Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're firing an event, and to keep this code portable, it's best to do your actions on the event itself instead of a specific item.

`var fArray = event.currentTarget.files;`

will do what you're after.